# textfieldをtapしてDialogを表示し、選択したものをtextfieldに表示したい

Tags: ios, android, flutter, dart

ダイアログを選択することはできるのだが、そのあとTextfieldに表示することができません。

試したコード

```
class Dialog extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PickerState createState() => _PickerState();
}

class _PickerState extends State<Dialog> {

  String _label = '';
  TextEditingController _textEditingController;

  void _setLabel(String s) {
    if (s == null) {
      return;
    }
    setState(() => _label = s);
  }

  Future _showSimpleDialog() async {
    String result = "";
    result = await showDialog(
      barrierDismissible: true,
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return SimpleDialog(
          title: Text('選択してください'),
          children: <Widget>[
            SimpleDialogOption(
              child: ListTile(
                title: Text('一大学'),
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(
                  context,
                  "一般大学",
                );
              },
            ),
            SimpleDialogOption(
              child: ListTile(
                title: Text('2大学'),
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(
                  context,
                  "2大学",
                );
              },
            ),
            SimpleDialogOption(
              child: ListTile(
                title: Text('3大学'),
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(
                  context,
                  "3大学",
                );
              },
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
    _setLabel(result);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: TextField(
        controller: _textEditingController,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          labelText: '大学',
          hintText: '大学',
          icon: Icon(Icons.school),
        ),
        onTap: _showSimpleDialog,
        onChanged: (value){
          setState(() {
            _label = value;
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TextEditingController`を使用して、文字列を設定してみてください。

```dart
class _PickerState extends State<Dialog> {
  String _label = '';
  TextEditingController _textEditingController;

  // 追加
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _textEditingController = TextEditingController();
  }

  void _setLabel(String s) {
    if (s == null) {
      return;
    }
    setState(() => _label = s);
    _textEditingController.text = s; // 追加
  }
～略～
```

Comment: ありがとうございます！！！